# Pytorch- why is “accumulating” the default mode of .gradient?

Tags: pytorch

Why didn't the authors just make it overwrite the gradient? Is there any specific reason for keeping it accumulated?

Answer (score 3):

Because if you use the same network twice (or same weights) in the forward pass, it should accumulate and not override. Also, since pytorch computation graph is defined by the run, so it makes sense to accumulate. See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903/9